# Значение и происхождение фразеологизма "с открытой душой"

Tags: фразеология

Comment: Что-то не верится, что Вы не знаете, что это значит. Если это школьное задание, то извольте делать его самостоятельно.

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki, значение-то он может и знает...
А вот происхождение. Мы о нем тут спорили. Вернее об аналогичном.

Answer (score 1):

[Душа нараспашку](http://www.dal.by/news/59/26-09-13-9/)

Еще в далекие времена на Руси считалось, что душа человека имеет свое место на теле, это ямочка между ключицами. И если какой-либо человек хотел показать, что у него нет дурных мыслей, он расстегивал пуговицу на рубашке, демонстрируя эту ямочку. Это обозначало, что человек живет с **открытой душой**, т. е. он искренен в своих мыслях и поступках.

Comment: Точно. Ведь никак больше и не покажешь, что нет дурных мыслей. Только, как если чего-нить ни расстегнувши.

Comment: Интересно, а мой запрос примут или нет. Смотрю он задан очень давно 4 года назад)))

Comment: Пока ожидаете, сделайте шаг назад — взгляните чуть шире — и подумайте, к примеру, над похожими словосочетаниями: большое сердце, чистые (загребущие, по локоть в крови) руки, длинный язык.